# On the equivalence of two definitions for summations over the integers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

If $a_k\in\mathbb{C}$, then define
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k=L\\
\Updownarrow\\\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N,m,n> N\implies\left|\sum_{k=-m}^na_k-L\right|<\epsilon
$$

**Question:** Is it true that

> $$
> \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k=L\\
> \Updownarrow\\
> \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\text{ and }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{-k}\text{ both exist and }\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{-k}=L
> $$

**Thoughts:**$[\Downarrow]$ Couldn't come up with something useful. Tried to show that both series are Cauchy. Failed.

$[\Uparrow]$ Let
$$
\alpha:=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\\
\beta:=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{-k}
$$
Given $\epsilon>0$, there exist $N_1,N_2$ such that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=0}^na_k-\alpha\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
\left|\sum_{k=1}^ma_{-k}-\beta\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
whenever $n>N_1$ and $m>N_2$. Hence if $N:=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ then
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=-m}^na_k-L\right|&=\left|\sum_{k=0}^na_k-\alpha+\sum_{k=1}^ma_{-k}-\beta\right|\\
&\leq\left|\sum_{k=0}^na_k-\alpha\right|+\left|\sum_{k=1}^ma_{-k}-\beta\right|\\
&<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&=\epsilon
\end{align}
whenever $m,n>N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant (adding quantors for $m,n$):

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N,\forall m > N, \forall n> N\implies\left|\sum_{k=-m}^na_k-L\right|<\epsilon.$$

The [$\Uparrow$] case is OK. For [$\Downarrow$], let $N(\epsilon)$ denote a suitable $N$ for $\epsilon$ in the above condition. If $n_2 > n_1 > N(\frac{\epsilon}{2})$, then $$\left|\sum_{n=n_1+1}^{n_2} a_n\right| = \left|\sum_{n=-n_1}^{n_2} a_n - \sum_{n=-n_1}^{n_1} a_n\right| = \left|\left(\sum_{n=-n_1}^{n_2} a_n -L \right) - \left(\sum_{n=-n_1}^{n_1} a_n - L\right)\right| \le \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon.$$

This means $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ is a Cauchy series. The proof for the negative part being Cauchy is done just the same.

Proving that $L$ is now the sum of the limits of the positive and negative parts works just as in the [$\Uparrow$] part.

**Adding remarks due to comment from OP below:**
That argument seems to work as well, but I was literally looking at your prove for $[\Uparrow]$. You start there by defining $\alpha$ and $\beta$. In that $[\Uparrow]$ proof that they exist is the assumption, in the $[\Downarrow]$ proof this was proven by them being Cauchy series'. Then you choose $\epsilon$ and based on that $N_1,N_2$. Then you use $L$ for the one and only time, but it is simply used as $L= \alpha + \beta$. So you proved that the $L$ defined that way fits your definition for "sum of series from $-\infty$ to $\infty$". Since that value is 'obviously' unique if it exists at all, you have now proven (in the $[\Downarrow]$ proof) that the value $L$ (which we assumed existed) must be equal to $\alpha + \beta$, which what was left to show.

Comment: Nice. When you say that proving that $L$ is the sum of the two series works just as in the proof of $[\Uparrow]$, what do you have in mind exactly? In that proof we are *given* that the sum is $L$. Did you have in mind that if $m,n>N(\epsilon)$ then $$\left|\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_k+\sum_{k=1}^ma_{-k}\right)-L\right|=\left|\sum_{k=-m}^na_k-L\right|<\epsilon$$ so that letting $n\to\infty$ first and $m\to\infty$ second we get $$\left|\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{-k}\right)-L\right|\leq\epsilon$$ and letting $\epsilon\to0$ gives equality?