# On the uniform convergence of series of functions with indexes in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123461/on-the-equivalence-of-two-definitions-for-summations-over-the-integers).

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. Is the definition below the common one for the uniform convergence of a series of functions of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}f_k$ ?
> 2. Are the statements of the three propositions below true and, if so, are their presented proofs correct?
> 3. Is the definition below a particular case of a more general definition, for example that of the uniform convergence of a net of functions (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Generalizations))? In case the propositions below are true, are they particular cases of more general results?

**Definition:** Let $E$ be a set and $f_k:E\to\mathbb{C}$ ($k\in\mathbb{Z}$) be functions. Say that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}f_k$ converges uniformly (on $E$) to $f:E\to\mathbb{C}$ if
$$
\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N,\forall m,n>N:\sup_{x\in E}\left|\sum_{k=-m}^nf_k(x)-f(x)\right|<\epsilon
$$

**Proposition:** $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}f_k$ converges uniformly to $f$ if, and only if, $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_{-k}$ both converge uniformly and $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k+\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_{-k}=f$.

**Proof:** $[\Leftarrow]$ Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there are functions $g,h:E\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $g+h=f$ for which
$$
\exists N_1,\forall n>N_1:\sup_{x\in E}\left|\sum_{k=0}^nf_k(x)-g(x)\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
\exists N_2,\forall m>N_2:\sup_{x\in E}\left|\sum_{k=1}^mf_{-k}(x)-h(x)\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
so that if $m,n>\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ then
\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in E}\left|\sum_{k=-m}^nf_k(x)-f(x)\right|&\leq\sup_{x\in E}\left|\sum_{k=0}^nf_k(x)-g(x)\right|+\sup_{x\in E}\left|\sum_{k=1}^mf_{-k}(x)-h(x)\right|\\
&<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&=\epsilon
\end{align}

$[\Rightarrow]$ Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $N$ such that
$$
\sup_{x\in E}\left|\sum_{k=-m}^nf_k(x)-f(x)\right|
$$
whenever $m,n>N$. Hence if $m>n>N$ then
\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in E}\left|\sum_{k=0}^mf_k(x)-\sum_{k=0}^nf_k(x)\right|&=\sup_{x\in E}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^mf_k(x)\right|\\
&=\sup_{x\in E}\left|\left(\sum_{k=-n}^mf_k(x)-f(x)\right)-\left(\sum_{k=-n}^nf_k(x)-f(x)\right)\right|\\
&\leq\sup_{x\in E}\left|\sum_{k=-n}^mf_k(x)-f(x)\right|+\sup_{x\in E}\left|\sum_{k=-n}^nf_k(x)-f(x)\right|\\
&<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&=\epsilon
\end{align}
This shows that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k(x)$ satisfies the Cauchy condition for uniform convergence and converges uniformly.

A similar argument shows that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_{-k}(x)$ also converges uniformly.

Finally,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_{-k}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}f_k=f
$$

**Proposition (Weierstrass M-test):** Let $f_k:E\to\mathbb{C}$ ($k\in\mathbb{Z}$) be functions and $M_k\geq0$ be real numbers such that $|f_k(x)|\leq M_k$ for all $x$ and all $k$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}M_k<\infty$. Then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}f_k$ converges uniformly on $E$.

**Proof:** Since $|f_k(x)|\leq M_k$ for all $x$ and all $k\geq0$ and
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}M_k\leq\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}M_k<\infty
$$
the usual version of the [Weierstrass M-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) shows that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k$ converges uniformly.

Similarly, $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_{-k}$ also converges uniformly.

By the above proposition, it follows that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}f_k$ converges uniformly.

**Proposition:** If $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $f_k:I\to\mathbb{C}$ are continuous for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}f_k$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $I$, then $f$ is continuous.

**Proof:** Then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_{-k}$ both converge uniformly, say to $g$ and $h$ respectively. So $g$ and $h$ are continuous. Since $f=g+h$, it follows that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is the definition below the common one for the uniform convergence of a series of functions of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}f_k$ ?

Yes, but there are situations (e.g. Fourier series) where one only considers the symmetric partial sums

$$\sum_{k = -n}^n f_k$$

and uses the same notation. In these cases, one says the series is uniformly convergent if the sequence of symmetric partial sums is uniformly convergent.

> 2. Are the statements of the three propositions below true and, if so, are their presented proofs correct?

Yes. But you forgot a $< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ at the beginning of the $[\Rightarrow]$ direction of the proof of the first proposition.

> 3. Is the definition below a particular case of a more general definition, for example that of the uniform convergence of a net of functions (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Generalizations))?

Yes. A series $\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} f_k$ is a special case of a net, the $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$-indexed net

$$F_{(m,n)} := \sum_{k = -m}^n f_k,$$

where the index set is endowed with the product order (that is, we have $(m_1,n_1) \leqslant (m_2,n_2)$ if and only if $(m_1 \leqslant m_2)\land (n_1 \leqslant n_2)$).

> In case the propositions below are true, are they particular cases of more general results?

The third proposition is definitely a particular case of the more general and immensely useful fact that the limit of a uniformly convergent net (or filter) of continuous functions is continuous.

The Weierstraß $M$-test is particular to series of functions. One can generalise it to arbitrary index sets, but since a sum of non-negative real numbers can only be finite if at most countably many of the numbers are non-zero, this isn't really a generalisation, it can however make the notation more convenient to allow arbitrary index sets. We can generalise the codomain; the same statement, with essentially the same proof works if the codomain is an arbitrary normed space. This is also useful.

I don't see a more general form for the first proposition (except for generalising the codomain), the splitting of the series into the part with negative indices and the part with non-negative indices (of course we could also split at any other integer, we're not tied to $0$) doesn't seem to have a more general close analogue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to be sure, both $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}f_k$ and $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f_k$ are limits of *different* nets, respectively $F_{(m,n)}$ as you described and $S_F:=\sum_{k\in F}f_k$ where the index set $\mathcal{F}$ is the collection of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ endowed with the inclusion order?

Comment: Usually. But sometimes $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is used to denote $\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}$. One can usually infer which is meant from the context if it isn't explicitly stated.