# $\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ versus $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, notation

If $a_k\in\mathbb{C}$ ($k\in\mathbb{Z}$), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123461/on-the-equivalence-of-two-definitions-for-summations-over-the-integers) are two equivalent definitions for
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k
$$
For reference, the two definitions are:

- $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k=L\\
  \Updownarrow\\\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N,m,n> N\implies\left|\sum_{k=-m}^na_k-L\right|<\epsilon$$
- $$
  \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k=L\\
  \Updownarrow\\
  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\text{ and }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{-k}\text{ both exist and }\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{-k}=L
  $$

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. Is the notation $\displaystyle\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_k$ usually *defined* to mean $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k$ (according to one of the two equivalent definitions given)?
> 2. Is the notation $\displaystyle\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_k$ a particular case of a definition of a summation of complex numbers over arbitrary index sets (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)#Summations_over_arbitrary_index_sets))?
> 3. If the answer to question 2. is *yes*, then are the definitions I just gave consistent with the general definition?

Comment: So, to put it in an example, your concern would be if a series like $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z},n\neq0}\text{sign}(n)\frac{1}{n}$ is convergent right? I'm interested...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a unanimous consensus on the meaning of the notation $\sum_{k\in\Bbb{Z}} a_k$, but it is often defines as one of the following equivalent notion:

1. $\sum_{k\in\Bbb{Z}} a_k$ is the limit of the net $ \{ \sum_{k \in F} a_k : F \subset \Bbb{Z} \text{ and $F$ is finite} \}$.
2. $\sum_{k\in\Bbb{Z}} a_k = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a_k$ when the series is absolutely convergent, i.e., $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} |a_k| < \infty$.

As you can see from the second definition, the sum $\sum_{k\in\Bbb{Z}} a_k$ is a strictly stronger notion than the doubly infinite sum $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a_k$.

**Example.** Let us consider $a_k = (-1)^k /k$ for $k \neq 0$ and $a_0 = 0$, then $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a_k = 0$ is easy to check. On the other hand, $\sum_{k\in\Bbb{Z}} a_k$ is simply undefined.

And the first definition is exactly a special case of the [definition introduced in your link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)#Summations_over_arbitrary_index_sets).

Comment: Do you have a reference for the equivalence of these two notions? Also, am I right if I say that a Fourier series is a series of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(k)e^{ikt}$ (*not* $\displaystyle\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(k)e^{ikt}$), but that Parseval's formula can be written equivalently as $$\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(k)|^2=\|f\|_2^2$$ or $$\displaystyle\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f}(k)|^2=\|f\|_2^2$$

Comment: @NeedForHelp, I am not sure about exact references, but it is a common exercise for those who learn the concept of the net.

Comment: For your second question, I guess it depends on which notion of convergence you are interested in. Certainly $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(k)e^{ikt} $ covers more general situation under pointwise convergence, but it is the same as $\sum_{k\in\Bbb{Z}} \hat{f}(k)e^{ikt} $ under $L^2$-convergence.

Answer (score 5):

Its the integral w.r.t. counting measure when $\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} \left| a_k \right| < \infty$, in which case equivalence is given by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

If $(a_k)$ is not absolutely summable, the definitions might not agree. For example, if $a_k = k$, the first definition gives a sum of $0$ while the second one is undefined.
(If the definition is taken to be the limit of symmetric sums)

(2) is true but does not necessarily holds for non-absolutely summable series. In which case the order of summation does matter and the sum can converge to any value in $\mathbb R$ if all $a_k$ are real.